# Parity in production

Tags: go-ethereum, parity

please share thoughts or experience of using parity in production vs geth, are there any other alternatives?

Maybe something like tierion.com but for ethereum exist?

Thanks!

Comment: https://blog.ethcore.io/performance-analysis/

Answer (score 8):

"it's clear Parity has head and shoulders the fastest and lightest Ethereum block processing engine amongst the available clients."

https://blog.ethcore.io/performance-analysis/

"Ok, so this graph shows up a few things. The first is the pronounced speed with which Parity processes the first 100k blocks in the chain, clocking up > 1000 blocks/second for most of the time during that period. Notably, these were the blocks while the thawing was going on, was a gas limit (and thus transaction volume) substantially below today's 3M - many of these contain no transactions in them at all. The fact that Geth's speedup isn't nearly so pronounced over this period rather suggests Geth has a bottleneck over and above proof-of-work verification."

"One of the most striking things about this graph is how consistent Geth is with its transaction processing compared to parity which is somewhat more dependent on the block. While the difference is liable to be somewhat overplayed since the values of transaction throughput for Parity are generally higher (and so we'd expect accordingly higher volatility over that value), it's nonetheless there. This is suggestive of bottlenecks outside of the paths strictly required for transaction processing."

Comment: I'd redo the comparison with a fresh version of Geth though. These benchmarks are from way back in February ;) Current Geth averages about 945 blocks/s on the first 100K on my machine.

Comment: Is there any way to test transaction throuhput with consistent transaction bodies (instead of simply seeing throughput of empty blocks)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using parity on my supernode and so far I can tell it's running more stable than the 1.3.x versions of geth which I used before that.

This, is of course no in-depth scientific researched answer, but you should give it a try. I'm very convinced that parity might be among the best ethereum clients of the future.

However, before going into production, you should learn about the differences of the RPC and IPC interfaces and test if your project works well.